# Can't seem to +1 javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a 1 after the previous number to a variable for it to add into the value of a textbox when the field is appended by the user. At this stage, it starts at one, click the plus icon, it goes to two. But press it again and it stays on two.

How can I add 1 onto the previous number?

```
function addAucField() {
    var fieldCount = 1;
    var newCount = parseInt(fieldCount+1);
    $("#addField").append("<br /><br />\n<input type=\"text\" name=\"aucSpots[]\" placeholder=\"Spot "+newCount+"\" class=\"span9\">");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The `parseInt` call is a bit pointless, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Follow your code ... top to bottom ... first you set `fieldCount` to 1, then you set `newCount` to the content of `fieldCount` (which is 1) plus 1. So `newCount` will always be 2. The rest you can figure out yourself

Comment: I suspect you've tried to simplify your code for this question?

Comment: @devnull69 - you don't think I've been trying? It stays on 2 no matter what.

Comment: You need to store `fieldCount` outside of the `addAucField()`, and also really add the value of `fieldCount`.

Comment: So where do you store the previous value? You need to store it somewhere in order to increment it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are adding **fieldCount**.. so whn clicked, **fieldCount** is 1 and function gets 2..bravoo.. works fine.. but then second click... **fieldCount** is 1 (again) ...  so gets 2 (so your function is fine...)...but output incorrect...SO put `fieldCount` outside the function.. and change it to newcount's value.. next time **fieldCount** is 2 and you'll get 3.

it should be

```
 var fieldCount = 1;
 function addAucField() {
    var newCount = parseInt(fieldCount+1);
    fieldCount=newCount;
    $("#addField").append("<br /><br />\n<input type=\"text\" name=\"aucSpots[]\" placeholder=\"Spot "+newCount+"\" class=\"span9\">");
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is every time the function addAucField() is called the fieldCount variable is set back to 1. Try to define it outside the function.

Comment: `fieldCount` is never set to anything but 1. Defining it outside the method won't change that. (Although it is a reasonable first step).

Comment: It is actually incremented inside the function, so why should't defining the variable outside the function change anything?

Comment: It is *not* incremented inside the function. `foo = bar + 1` does not modify `bar`.

Comment: yes you are right sorry, i didn't see that he forgot to write the new value into the variable

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a closure and actually increment `fieldCount`:

```
var addAucField = (function() {
    var fieldCount = 1;
    return function() {    
        var newCount = ++fieldCount; // increment fieldCount
        $("#addField").append("<br /><br />\n<input type=\"text\" name=\"aucSpots[]\" placeholder=\"Spot "+newCount+"\" class=\"span9\">");
        return false;
    };
})();
```

You could also make `fieldCount` global, but it's almost always a bad idea to pollute the global namespace. Note that you **need to increment `fieldCount`**:

```
var fieldCount = 1;
function addAucField(){
    var newCount = ++fieldCount; // increment fieldCount
    $("#addField").append("<br /><br />\n<input type=\"text\" name=\"aucSpots[]\" placeholder=\"Spot "+newCount+"\" class=\"span9\">");
    return false;
 };
```

Comment: And you won't say that this would be "shooting sparrows with a canon"?

Comment: @devnull69: If I potentially introduce a technique which might be unknown to OP it's justified.

Answer (score -3):

How about changing `var newCount = parseInt(fieldCount+1);` into `var newCount = parseInt(fieldCount)+1;`

(Untested)